# How can I extract information about an ontology through the URI using Jena

Tags: java, uri, jena, ontology, apache-jena

I want to extract information about an ontology that has the uri = http://dmir.inesc-id.pt/project/DataStorm/2014/0/PipelinePatterns
for that I use the Jena framework and I do the follow,

```
OntModel ontModel = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
ontModel.getDatatypeProperty(uri);
```

I try also

```
OntModel ontModel = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
OntModel model = ontModel.getImportedModel(uri);
```

and finally I try to convert an URI to a file but nothing of this work.

I want to know if it's possible to access to an ontology through URI and extract the information using Jena framework.

Comment: "I want to know if it's possible to access to an ontology through URI and extract the information using Jena framework."  Yes, you can load a model from a URI.  However, when I try to retrieve that URI, I see a wiki page saying, "There is currently no text in this page. You can search for this page title in other pages, or search the related logs." Do you have any  reason to suppose that you're supposed to be able to load RDF content from that URI?

Comment: I has this ontology in a owl file and when I use Protege and open this file I see an URI so I assume that exists. But did you know some ontology URI that Works? Just to test. Thank you

Comment: I'm not quite clear what you mean.  You can give an ontology any URI you want.  That doesn't have anything to do with whether you can *retrieve* that ontology from that URI.  E.g., you can call an ontology `http://www.example.org/someOntology`, but that doesn't mean you can retrieve any content from there.  There are lots of publicly available OWL ontologies though.  E.g., [http://www.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~michael/sw/slides/pizza.owl](http://www.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~michael/sw/slides/pizza.owl).

Comment: My code, https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5zezH8sUUrGQWh3MTdNMnlKaDg/view?usp=sharing

now I want to use model to extract the DatatypeProperty from the uri that I receive (in this example is http://www.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~michael/sw/slides/pizza.owl) but the model is null. 

Thanks and I'm sorry for my English